# AWS autoscaling desired capacity changes automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS Autoscaling feature with target Tracking policy having CPU utilisation above 20 percent will scale out my group and should scale in once CPU goes down.
My Min value is 1, Desired is 1 and Max 4
But once i test a heavy load it scales out perfectly by dosent scale in once i stop my load generator, as i can always see my desired capacity is modified to 3 or 4 rather than my default 1.

Kindly help.

Comment: How long did you wait? You could be running in to [scaling cooldowns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html)

Comment: I waited for 10 minutes, and i kept very small cool down period.